# Using github API how to get commits listed\associated to an issue

Tags: api, github

When a commit references an issue the issue itself will be "tagged" with the commit. See the image below as an example.

I believe commits are "referenced events".  But looking at the list of (ref) events the commit_id and\or the commit_url are not populated.  And then using the event url does not seem to give back the info either.

Any suggestions?

[image]